# Get "tried to synchronously call function from a different thread" with Swift/ React Native/ Frame Processor Plugin

Tags: swift, react-native

The goal is that OtherPlugin.callback (which is also a swift module in the project) has logic that evaluates some input data  but even with this commented out, the code still fails. The project is using Reanimated along with `react-native-vision-camera`. With Reanimated, Worklets are supposed to run on the UI thread, and that is where the EventEmitter is supposed to run, but it appears that somewhere it is being mistaken for a synchronous call. Actual error points to the function call for `useFrameProcessor()` but if I remove the eventEmitter, then console.log works as expected. Also, if I try to runOnJs(eventEmitter), then it says that "process" is not a recognized Objective-C method. Thanks for the help in advance

**Implementation.m**

```swift
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <React/RCTBridgeModule.h>
#import <React/RCTEventEmitter.h>


@interface RCT_EXTERN_MODULE(LabelEventEmitter, RCTEventEmitter)

RCT_EXTERN_METHOD(process:(NSDictionary *)frame)

@end
```

**EventEmitter.swift**

```swift
import Foundation


@objc(LabelEventEmitter)
class LabelEventEmitter: RCTEventEmitter{
  
  override static func requiresMainQueueSetup() -> Bool{
    return false;
  }
  override func supportedEvents() -> [String]! {
    return ["Results"]
  }


  @objc
  func process(_ frame:Frame!){
//    let results = OtherPlugin.callback(frame, withArgs: [])!
    let results = ["foo":"bar"] as [String : Any]
    sendEvent(withName: "Results", body: results)

  }
}
```

**React native Component**

```
    const frameProcessor = useFrameProcessor((frame)=>{
        'worklet'
        LabelEventEmitter.process(frame) // This code fails, RN says it's synchronous?

        
        //@ts-ignore
        console.log("Running on UI threads") // this works
     
     
    }, [])
```